# How many generations could a small group go without suffering the effects of inbreeding

Tags: genetics, sex

With a group of twelve human couples stranded on a island, how many generations could they go before becoming infertile due to inbreeding?

Comment: Depends on how lucky they are, doesn't it? If they are *really* lucky they could grow and multiply and take over the world.

Comment: @AlexP explain?

Comment: Inbreeding *in itself* does not have to lead to bad effects. It's just that quite often it does result in an increased rate of genetic diseases. But it does not have to; if the population is extraordinarily lucky then none of the twelve founders carries any genetic defect. Or if they are only very but not extraordinarily lucky then none of the founders carries any seriously debilitating defect. The point being that inbreeding is bad only in the statistical sense; after all, some people *do* win the lottery.

Comment: It may depend partly on how diverse the 12 couples are.

Comment: @AlexP How does 'It's just that quite often it does result in an increased rate of genetic diseases…' deal with the Hapsburg lip, or eyes of many of the present British royals? As below, how do you rule out Egyptian pharoahs?

Comment: Do you think there might be all the difference in the world between monogamous couples, where six males and six females gives six pairings, and promiscuous couples where six of each might give 36 pairings. What if each ratio is perpetuated down the generations? Still, what makes you think 12 pairs is enough in any circumstances?

Comment: Inbreeding causes potential (pre-breeding age) deaths in population with bad genetic mixes. The genetic lottery will (assuming the population isn't hopelessly filled with  genetic problems) have at least some babies that will mature to breeding age. Inbreeding will cause a lot of deaths, but some babies will survive to breed, and these will tend to be freer of genetic defects. This is how small breeding pools can survive; it requires an environment that allows for a lot of babies and a population that is willing to accept lots of infant mortality.

Comment: Long before inbreeding comes into the mix, 12 couples means 24 joint ancestors, yes? More than enough to establish a useful gene pool, if they're promiscuous… contrary to general human morality, but necessary for biological diversity… and please note how important 'more than' is.

In your view, how could the possible varieties 12 monogamous couples offered to the race be genetically more - or as - useful than the varieties offered by 24 polygamous people?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  That doesn't seem to make sense. Wouldn't Polyamory only increase the chance of you doing it with your sister? I would think they would need not only monogamy but arranged marriage to maximize genetic diversity and prevent the hashburgs effect?

Comment: @Bryan McClure That does make sense, so long as we're talking about genetics and not theoretical morality.

That kind of polyamory doesn't simply increase the chance of you doing it with your siblings; it makes that necessary in the early generations.

For how many generations that's necessary, for how many after that it's  useful and after how many it becomes detrimental, you'd need to ask some expert geneticists but don't you see, the general theory is too simply obvious to challenge?

More…

Comment: @BryanMcClure Consider you and your sister the only survivors of an extinction level event… however absurd the suggestion.

To preserve the species, what should you do?

Comment: @Robie Goodwin  My concern genetic not necessarily moral.    Incest would only result in inbreeding which is what they are trying to avoid. Worse yet in this low population it can result in the habsburg effect.  We're not only do you impregnate your sister But her son impregnates His sister as well, And so on. This can lead To compound the already negative effects of inbreeding and incest. the last habsburg  King of Spain had parents that while cousins were genetically much closer than siblings.

Comment: I didn't understand how difficult this could be to put across.

For any group - here, 12 - isn't the need, to maximise the gene pool?

For 12 half female, half male, isn't the obvious way to maximise the gene pool to use every possible coupling?

To minimise in-breeding problems, the next generation should also maximise the coupling possibilities.

Whether that will work is down to either luck, or simple Mendelian genetics

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin   I see your logic, It might Work but only If it was highly formal and regulated.  You need to keep careful track over who Was related to who. Otherwise you just end up inbreeding more.  Partners would be temporary and arranged, With harsh penalties for sleeping with someone other than You're currently asigned partner, And even harsher penalties for sleeping with a 1/2 sibling, or other relative.

Comment: That's true and why might it be a problem for your group… or for you?

How could it matter if breeding was formal or regulated, if the group was educated?

Of course for the first few generations, careful track over relationships would need to be kept. Why might that be a problem?

Other than your personal idea of morality, why might it matter if partners were arranged?

Which society have you heard of that does not penalise sleeping with a relative?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  Never said it would be a problem. Only that it would have to be done in order to prevent problems.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Sure and however tiny a minority I'm in, I did not understand from your Comment. I thought 'only If it was highly formal and regulated' described a problem. What else might 'but only' have meant?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I was only saying that this system of mating could easily back fire so it would have to be regulated to a nearly draconian levels. It could work though so long as you were willing to take it that far. It's not a problem unless people aren't willing to give up that much freedom.

Comment: @Bryan McClure Did I fail to show how regulation was much of my point?

What makes you think the necessary regulation might need to approach Draconian levels?

Comment: Is to prevent inviting and do maximize sexual diversity. You will need to keep track Whose child was which

Comment: You would need to keep track of who was the offspring of who, For that who the father was must not be in doubt. Meaning every female must only be with one male at a time.

Comment: This also would prevent some particularly horny guy or gal From being over represented  In the next generation's genetic pool.

Comment: At the same time you want as much genetic diversity as possible or else you wouldn't use this route. So every female must have  At least one child for every 1 of the males. Meaning that you wouldn't be able to stay with the partner you liked For very long.

Comment: This from my perspective sounds pretty Draconian. But edmediately I'm coming from my own cultural assumptions. Perhaps someone from a different culture may disagree.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Could you just look back at the whole thread, then clearly state whether you might have changed anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The Science

The big problem with inbreeding is the potential for genetic diseases to cause problems.  This is *usually* related to the increased risk from a "bad" genetic variant which exists in a founding population.  For example, suppose that a disease is tied to a single recessive allele (sickle cell anemia is, kind of, an example of this).  A person who has one copy of the disease-causing allele (the "bad" variant) will be fine, while a person with two copies of the bad variant will be afflicted with the disease.

In a large population, it is likely that the prevalence of the bad variant of a gene will be relatively low (there is selective pressure which will, in general, select against the variant).  As such, if two random people from a large population have children together, there is a relatively small chance of passing on a bad variant gene from both parents, and a correspondingly small chance that their children will be afflicted this recessive genetic ailment.

However (in this simplified model), any individual who has a copy of the disease-causing variant has a 50% chance of passing that variant on to their children.  As such, if one sibling has the bad variant, then there is a 50/50 chance that the other will, as well.  Hence there is a 25% chance that, if these siblings have children, those children will have two copies of the bad variant, and will be afflicted by this genetic disease.

Therefore having children with close relatives is risky because it increases the chance of passing on "bad" recessive genes.

However, if the founding population is free of these bad variants, or if there is significant genetic diversity in the founding population, then the chance any one individual having (and passing on) a dangerous recessive genetic ailment is relatively small.  Hence population bottlenecks are not instant doom for a species (for example, it appears that every person in the Americas prior to European contact is descended from a population of around 70 people who crossed over Berengia around 15,000 years ago; 130 years ago, there were around [20 Northern elephant seals], the current population over 30k).

Thus, from a *scientific* standpoint, a small founder population could go on to establish a population which survives indefinitely.

#### Storytelling

As this is a question on Worldbuilding SE, rather than some other SE site, the *actual* question here is "In a fictional setting, how long could a population founded by a small group persist?"

The answer to *that* question is:  it is up to the author.

If it is important for the plot that the colony is at risk of collapse due to a lack of genetic diversity, then the colony is at risk of collapse due to a lack of genetic diversity.

Answer (score 7):

### Indefinitely

It is believed that every Cheetah alive today descends from a population bottleneck of [at most seven individuals that lived roughly 10,000 years ago](https://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/1999/08/02/40791.htm). This is far more extreme than a reduction to 12 couples, and did not result in infertility.

There are other problems that result from a lack of genetic diversity but there's no reason to believe that infertility would result.

Comment: While I'm not sure about animals.   I can think of multiple examples of inbreeding resarting an infertility in humans. The Egyptian pharaohs,  And of course the infamous hasburg's.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Individual cases of infertility, sure, but the whole population? No, not even in those cases. Also, infertility occurs at pretty high rates anyway so it's impossible to definitively link these cases to inbreeding.

Comment: the consistent trend of infertile in Egyption pharaohs suggests otherwise.

Comment: @BryanMcClure for that to happen, it means that one pharaoh had the gene to cause infertility and it was was never selected out of that small population, not that inbreeding caused it.  Incest was very common across all of Egypt for religious reasons, and that did not stop them from being one of the most densely populated regions in the ancient world.

Comment: @Nosajimiki this was a problem for multiple dynasties not just one and hastburs as well

Comment: @BryanMcClure Yes it was, but it was also not a problem for multiple dynasties as well. About 19% of people have infertility issues.  Depending on how many of those problems come from recessive genes, it means that a human  incestious bloodline has about a 20-40% chance of forming a pattern of infertility... that also means you have a 60-80% chance of no problems at all.

Comment: It's also important to understand that a single line of succession _isn't_ a population. By their very nature, infertility problems are heavily selected against and thus will always tend to be purged from a population.

Comment: @JackAidley True.  When you are a king, things that are normally a death sentence (or at least grossly reduce your odds of mating) become far less likely to weed you out of the gene pool.

Comment: @Nosajimiki When you say not a problem for many different dynasties are you talking Egyptian dynasty is cause I'm only talking Egyptian dynamistics.

Comment: @BryanMcClure If you want to focus on Ancient Egyptian culture, they were by far the most incestious civilization in human history: not just pharoses, but at all levels of society.  They saw the incestious relationships of thier gods as the preferred method for match making, so when you came of age, you were expected to marry your sibling if any were available, otherwise it was 1st cousin, etc.  Marrying an unrelated person was considered an act of last recourse; so, if infertility was a guaranteed outcome of incest, then we would have seen huge birth rate issues in ancient Egypt.

Comment: ... yet it was consistently one of the most densely populated Mediterranean regions for 1000s of years. Presumably, most bloodlines rich in dangerous recessive disorders died out early on until the prevalence of recessive disorders was similar to dominant disorders. The bigger issue is actually pairing genetic lines arbitrarily with leadership.  Royalty is automatically unlikely to be selected against, so when a royal bloodline picks up a genetic disorder of any kind, it's more likely to persist.

Comment: Just two moments, please; at least.

Various Answers and Comments here suggest 'genetic diseases' might be a problem.

They might, and if inbreeding makes them more likely, someone might explain… please?

Failing detailed explanations surely, 'everyone knows' the Hapsburg lip, the Windsor eyes and such like problems are genetic.

Specifically, which 'genetic diseases' can you cite?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Stable Genetics (Biiiiiig Assumption) and no pre-existing Genetic conditions and fixed environmental conditions - there's no reason why it couldn't go on forever.

The problem is that Genetics aren't completely stable and that the Environment is never fixed - You could look at some of the European Monarchies as case-studies in in-breeding and draw some conclusions from that.